# Fetching record of integer type Using WHERE clause that matches part of the value provided as input

Tags: java, mysql, string, jdbc, integer

MySql+java

I want to retrieve records using WHERE clause

column: SecCode int(11) have values like this, 221101101, 221101102, 221302551, so on....

i am passing query as below:

```
query = "select distinct(SecName) from sector_mst where SecCode Like="+ myvalue +"%"
```

myvalue has values like 2211, 2212, 2213, and so on....

"I know it is of integer type hence i am getting error"

Also i cannot use make of = operator as  **SecCode = myvalue**...
because 221101101 != 2211

can i compare or match only first 4 digits of SecCode (2211...) with myvalue(2211)
and i am not able to figure out any other way to do this....
Thanks...

Comment: what error you getting ?

Comment: my friend next to me solved it....but thanx you all were correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the syntax. You've incorrectly used `=` operator with `LIKE` and have forgotten to use quotes.

```
select distinct(SecName)
from sector_mst
where SecCode like '"+ myvalue +"%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this

```
public class Test {     
    public static void main( String [] args) 
    { 
          String Str = new String("221101101 ");
          System.out.println(Str.matches("2211(.*)"));
    } 
}
```

this will compare the first four charcter and will ignore the rest

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
query = "select distinct(SecName) from sector_mst where SecCode Like '"+ myvalue +"'%' "
```